# Is it possible to access as3 custom properties from javascript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I have the following property defined in my webcam as3 webcam class

```
public function get paused():Boolean
  {
  return (cam == null);
  }

public function set paused(p:Boolean):void
  {
  if(p){picture.draw(vid,flip);cam = null;}
  else cam = Camera.getCamera();
  vid.attachCamera(cam);
  }
```

Is it possible to access this from javascript?  When I had it as a simple function it worked with:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("paused", paused);
```

But that wont compile after I changed it to properties.

"Error: Implicit coercion of a value of type Boolean to an unrelated type Function."

I'm an actionscript newbie so maybe there's something obvious I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`addCallback()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29) only accepts a function, so you'll need to create meaningful functions that set and get the value without the use of the `get` and `set` keywords:

```
function getPaused():Boolean
{
    return paused;
}

function setPaused(value:Boolean):void
{
    paused = value;
}

ExternalInterface.addCallback("getPaused", getPaused);
ExternalInterface.addCallback("setPaused", setPaused);
```

Comment: Yes I know it's a property but question is how can I access this property from javascript?

Comment: In javascript I was hoping to use something like "cam.paused=true".  Is that not possible?

Comment: @poby You'll need to approach it as I've described in my latest edit - the ExternalInterface API only allows you to expose methods. This way you would do `cam.setPaused(true);` instead.